# how should I change the cell that is resulted from diff()?

Tags: python, pandas

For example in this data frame I used groupby and diff with this command

```
df['app_usage_time']=df.groupby(['label','date'])['time'].diff(1):
```

My goal is to calculate the usage of each app for each user for every day (in the whole dataset the dates are different) and the usage time of each app is the time that one app has been started until another app will be started (telegram usage time for P2 in the first line = 13:16:20.742000 - 13:14:57.144000= 00:01:23.598000 ) actually I want to put the answer in front of the telegram not in front of the whatsapp. What should I do?

```
 label   date            time         application          app_usage_time  
  P2  2019-11-07  13:14:57.144000      telegram                   NaT  
  P5  2019-11-07  13:15:31.649000      whatsapp                   NaT  
  P5  2019-11-07  13:15:49.573000      whatsapp               00:00:17.924000  
  P2  2019-11-07  13:16:20.742000      whatsapp               00:01:23.598000  
  P4  2019-11-07  13:16:33.894000      facebook                   NaT  
  P4  2019-11-07  13:16:35.270000      instagram              00:00:01.376000  
  P5  2019-11-07  13:16:35.926000      telegram               00:00:46.353000  
  P8  2019-11-07  13:16:36.755000      Instagram                  NaT  
  P4  2019-11-07  13:16:37.801000      whatsapp               00:00:02.531000  
  P4  2019-11-07  13:16:37.864000      facebook               00:00:00.063000  
  P8  2019-11-07  13:16:38.154000      telegram               00:00:01.399000  
  P4  2019-11-07  13:16:39.364000      whatsapp               00:00:01.500000
```

I have also another question. How can we put the values of a column consecutive after groupby: here I want the labels to be consecutive:

```
p2 
p2
P4
P4
P4
P4
P4
p5 
p5
p5
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the answer for the previous record instead of the next one

```
df['app_usage_time'] = -df.groupby(['label','date'])['time'].diff(-1)
```

To sort them, you do

```
df.sort_values(['label', 'date', 'time'], inplace=True)
```